# Duplicate the first ten rows and reorder the date

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I am a beginner. Currently, I want to duplicate the first ten rows of my dataframe (over 100 rows of date ddmmyyyy and flow as below. The reorder the first ten rows, in which the date from the last (20/1/2022 - 1/1/2022).

| Date | Flow |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 12 |
| 2/1/2022 | 9 |
| ....... |  |
| 30/5/2022 | 0.4 |

I don't know how to work out and anyone can help me pls?

Comment: read notice : [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-5-30', freq='D'),
                   'Flow': range(150)})
```

Create a new indexer and reindex:

```
N = 10

out = df.iloc[np.r_[np.arange(N)[::-1], np.arange(1, len(df))]]
```

Or, with `concat`:

```
N = 10

out = pd.concat([df.iloc[N-1:0:-1], df], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
          Date  Flow
9   2022-01-10     9
8   2022-01-09     8
7   2022-01-08     7
6   2022-01-07     6
5   2022-01-06     5
4   2022-01-05     4
3   2022-01-04     3
2   2022-01-03     2
1   2022-01-02     1
0   2022-01-01     0
1   2022-01-02     1
2   2022-01-03     2
3   2022-01-04     3
4   2022-01-05     4
5   2022-01-06     5
6   2022-01-07     6
7   2022-01-08     7
8   2022-01-09     8
9   2022-01-10     9
10  2022-01-11    10
11  2022-01-12    11
12  2022-01-13    12
..         ...   ...
145 2022-05-26   145
146 2022-05-27   146
147 2022-05-28   147
148 2022-05-29   148
149 2022-05-30   149

[160 rows x 2 columns]
```

###### original answer

You can first extract the first 10 rows, sort in reverse order (or just reverse if already sorted in ascending order), then duplicate with [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and concatenate with the rest of the indices, finally [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
N = 10
order = (df['Date'].iloc[:N]
         .sort_values(ascending=False)
         .index
         )

out = df.reindex(np.r_[order.repeat(2), df.index[N:]])
```

Output:

```
          Date  Flow
9   2022-01-10     9
9   2022-01-10     9
8   2022-01-09     8
8   2022-01-09     8
7   2022-01-08     7
7   2022-01-08     7
6   2022-01-07     6
6   2022-01-07     6
5   2022-01-06     5
5   2022-01-06     5
4   2022-01-05     4
4   2022-01-05     4
3   2022-01-04     3
3   2022-01-04     3
2   2022-01-03     2
2   2022-01-03     2
1   2022-01-02     1
1   2022-01-02     1
0   2022-01-01     0
0   2022-01-01     0
10  2022-01-11    10
11  2022-01-12    11
..         ...   ...
145 2022-05-26   145
146 2022-05-27   146
147 2022-05-28   147
148 2022-05-29   148
149 2022-05-30   149

[160 rows x 2 columns]
```